# Fetch Python Logger Formatter Variables in Code

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

I have a Django project and this is what the logger formatter configuration looks like.

```
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s SCORPIO [%(request_id)s] ' + os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'] + ': %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
    },
},
```

How does Python pick the different variables (asctime, request_id) provided in the format? I need to fetch the request_id variable in case of a failure and display it on a page.

I've mostly worked with Java in which these variables are picked from the ThreadContext so I tried looking for such an alternative in Python but couldn't find one.

Comment: Can you see it in the `request.META` dict?

Comment: Nope, it's not there.